# how to compare array data with different row values in database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to compare my array data with database data,actually I'll get array values from the server. I don't know it's correct or not so that's why I want to compare these array values with my database values -- to see if it's present or not. The problem is that I'll get values in array format like:

```
"tag_id":
[
 "1",
 "2",
 "3"
]
```

I have a database table where values are like:

1. betty
2. kristi
3. edward

for this I use this code:

```
$array_tag_id = implode(',', $json_object['tag_id']);
//check if tag id correct or not. 
$match_tag_id = mysqli_query($con, "select tag_id from Wheel_Tag where tag_id like $array_tag_id[0]");
```

I think it's not correct for comparing my array data with database row data. How to compare with database row values?

Can I create an array for database table id's value and then compare with the server array values?

Now I just tried this, but it's not working.

```
$array1 = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tag_id FROM Wheel_Tag");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))}
{$array1 = array_merge($array1, array_map('trim', explode(",", 
$row['tag_id'])));}
$match_tag_id = mysqli_query($con,"select tag_id from Wheel_Tag where 
tag_id like '$array1'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($match_tag_id) > 0){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($match_tag_id)){
       $get_tag_id = $row['tag_id'];
    }
}
```

but I think it's not correct.

How to convert json into an php array?

Comment: What do you want to compare exactly? If something in your array is also in database?

Comment: can you please post the full array values?

Comment: actually i'll get array values from the server,i don't know it's correct or not so thats why i want to compare this array valuse with my database values if it's present or not so how can i compare??

Comment: what's the possible value of tag_id column? what is this: `id user_name 1 betty 2 kristi 3 edward`

Comment: i updated my question like that i have database value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IN ()` instead of `LIKE`

```
$json_str = 'JSON CODE';
$json_arr = json_decode($json_str, 1); <<-- flag 1 to output as array
$tag_ids = implode(',', $json_arr['tag_id']);


select tag_id from Wheel_Tag where tag_id IN ($tag_ids)
```

Comment: this code will be work but it's only for knowing values .if i wont know which values coming in array so thn i can't put IN{1,2,3} in my code.

Comment: this was an example! wait i will do the php script for you.

Comment: no,it's not working Gustonez..i think i have to use array for comparing.

Comment: do u know..how to store database value in an array and thn check with post array values???